# How to forward current plus previous studies from a patient on DCM4CHEE using the forwarding service?

Tags: java, xslt

I was looking to see if someone could point me toward an XSL script example to achieve the following: Whenever a new study is pushed to an dcm4chee instance, that instance should forward that study and all previous studies from the same patient to another dcm4chee instance.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some examples on how to use the foward2 service under the server/default/conf/dcm4chee-ae directory. To enable previous studies just need to have destination tag with the following attribute:

```
<destination aet="KPServer" includePrior="true"/>
```

and the correspondent forward_priors.xsl file. You can use the one giving on the example.